# How can I build OpenSSL for OP-TEE small trusted OS?

Tags: openssl, op-tee

I want to build OpenSSL 1.0.2 for [optee_os](https://github.com/OP-TEE/optee_os). 
But OpenSSL is very large and has a lot of dependencies(c library f.e.). 
OP-TEE has no c-library (and others).

Can I build OpenSSL with only crypto algorithms?
(without files, z-lib and so on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSL has a large number of compile time options which enable you to switch off various features. However there is no way to remove the need for an underlying C library, e.g. it sill needs basics like malloc/free/memcpy/strcpy etc.

z-lib support is not built by default anyway. You can switch off various i/o capabilities with the "no-stdio", "no-posix-io", "no-sock" and "no-dgram" compile time options. You might also want to consider the "no-async" and "no-dso" options.

Full details of the compile time options are available here:
https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1-stable/INSTALL